# Communication between Raspberry Pi over Wifi

Tags: gpio, wifi, linux

I want to interface some sensors with my raspberry pi via GPIO UART serial communication and then transmit the data to another raspberry pi via wifi. I am not a pro. Any good tutotial or technique?